# Setting interface NM_CONTROLLED to yes using nmcli in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm writing some documentation on configuring the network interfaces for a new CentOS 7 server. The specific section walks through setting the interface to a static IP address.

The steps thus far are:

```
# nmcli con mod eno16777984 ipv4.address 192.168.1.31/24
# nmcli con mod eno16777984 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
# nmcli con mod eno16777984 ipv4.method manual
# nmcli con mod eno16777984 ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
# nmcli con reload eno16777984
```

I notice though, that the above steps don't set the interfaces IP to the static IP set above (via `ip addr show`), when I restart the network service via `systemctl`, it breaks the networking config (my connection dies). I log back in via the terminal and add `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` to the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777984, and restart networking again, and it works just fine.

So basically, I just want to know if it's possible to set the `NM_CONTROLLED` value to *yes*, using `nmcli` itself?

I know I can just `echo 'NM_CONTROLLED=yes' > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777984`, but I was trying to script this out via `nmcli` itself.

I couldn't find much on this, so it may not be possible, but I thought id at least find out for sure

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to change NM_CONTROLLED via nmcli, because that property is not a regular property of NM's connection. It's a special setting to tell NM and ibiscripts whether the device is managed by NM or not.

Side note: `nmcli con reload eno16777984` is wrong. First, after `nmcli con mod` you don't need to reload any connections. Second, reload doesn't accept an argument as it reloads all connections.
Also, when using NM, you would normally not restart network service, but `nmcli con up ...`.